# Bizarre Dataframe Structure after using dplyr Lead

Tags: r, dplyr

I simply want to get the lead value for a set of grouped records.  See below

```
dat <- data.frame(ids = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4))
dat$id <- 1:nrow(dat)
library(dplyr)

y <- tbl_df(dat) %>% 
  group_by(ids) %>% 
  mutate(next_id = lead(id, 1))
```

And when you look at the structure of `y`

```
> str(y)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ids    : num  1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4
 $ id     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ next_id: int  2 3 4 NA NA NA 8 NA
 - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  ..$ : symbol ids
 - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':  4 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ids: num  1 2 3 4
  ..- attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : symbol ids
  ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 4
  ..$ : int  0 1 2 3
  ..$ : int 4
  ..$ : int 5
  ..$ : int  6 7
```

What I was expecting was just a simple `int` column, not a nested data structure.

I am sure that I am missing something obvious, but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That did the trick, I always forget about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @David's comment from above, `ungroup` is the key.

```
dat <- data.frame(ids = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4))
dat$id <- 1:nrow(dat)
library(dplyr)

y <- tbl_df(dat) %>% 
  group_by(ids) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(next_id = lead(id, 1))
str(y)

> str(y)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ids    : num  1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4
 $ id     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ next_id: int  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 NA
```

Comment: I guess you want to put the ungroup after the mutate